# How to find the first existing file in a sequence

Tags: r

I have several locations which may contain a file I need.

I want to find the first existing file in a vector.

Both

```
find.existing.file <- function (files) {
  present <- which(file.exists(files))
  stopifnot(length(present) > 0)
  files[present[1]]
}
```

and

```
find.existing.file <- function (files) {
  for (i in 1:length(files))
    if (file.exists(files[i]))
      return(files[i])
  stop("None exist: ",paste(files,collapse=" "))
}
```

should be doing what I need.

However, the first version checks all the files instead of returning on the first existing file, while the second uses a loop which, I think, is not very "R'y".

I was wondering whether I was missing something obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: By the nature of the beast this is a sequential operation, and unless you'd like to write your own `C++` function, a loop like in your second solution is the way to go (assuming you have a large number of files to check).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here another option using regular expression, and `list.files`. I assume you search for a list of files in an existing directory.

```
function(listfiles,path)
  length(grep(paste(listfiles,collapse='|'),
              list.files(path))> 0
```

**EDIT** after OP clarification:

To search for a certain file in many location you can just `list.files` with a specific pattern.
For example, to search for init files in /etc, /usr/local/etc:

```
list.files(path= c('/etc','/usr/local/etc'),
           pattern='init.*')
```

Comment: thanks. actually, what I had in mind was more like looking in several places for a specific file (like a program may look for its init file in `/etc`, then in `/usr/local/etc` &c.)

Comment: cool, this is even more interesting. however, this will still check files which are not going to be used. but this is not, I guess, a big deal (unless one of the `path`s is on a stale NFS).

Comment: @sds no experience with stale NFS(I am not an advanced linux user). But reading a little bit about the problem  I think it is external to `list.files`. You can for example run something like `system("umount -f stale_path") ...` before the search command.

Answer (score 1):

This looks ["functional"](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) enough:

```
find.existing.file <- function (files)
  Find(file.exists,files,nomatch=stop("None exist: ",paste(files, collapse=" ")))
```